# Prove the radius of convergence of the complex power series $(z^2 - 1)/(z^3-1)$ about $z =2$ is sqrt(7)

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion, partial-fractions

So first I took the partial fractions and removed the singularity $z-1$ so I have $f(z) = \frac{z+1}{z^2+z+1}$. Then I took the complex root of the denominator so now I have $f(z) = \frac{z+1}{(z-e^{2/3\pi i})(z+e^{2/3\pi i})}$. I am confused on where to go from here. I have tried plugging 2 in for $z$, trying to find zero points by using the unit circle, I am lost.

Comment: Find the distance from $z=2$ to the closest of those singularities. Remember that the power series will converge all the way until it bumps a singular point. In this problem $2$ is real and the (non-removable) singularities a conjugates of each other. Therefore, both distances are the same.

Comment: I know I need to do that, but I am having trouble going about it. My book isn't doing a very good job of explaining how and i've already exhausted my attempts

Comment: To compute the distance is just a calculation: $|2-e^{2\pi i/3}|^2=2^2+|e^{2\pi i/3}|^2-2Re(2e^{2\pi i/3})=4+1-4Re(e^{2\pi i /3})$. Since $Re(e^{2\pi i /3})=-1/2$, we get that $|2-e^{2\pi i/3}|^2=7$. By the way the roots of the denominator are not $\pm e^{2\pi i/3}$. They are $e^{\pm2\pi i/3}$.

Comment: Is  |2−e2πi/3|^2 using the formula |Z-Zo| = r? If not, how did you get it?

Comment: Read the first comment. The series converges on a disc with center the center of the expansion $z=2$ and radius as large as to meet the closest (non-removable) singularity. Since both singularities are at the same distance from $2$, you only need to compute the distance from $2$ to one of them.

Comment: Right I get that. Also, I know the roots aren't +/- rather their exponents are +/-  but in my book it said it was so could you explain why I am using the positive exponent with its conjugate?

Comment: Your book is wrong, if it says that.

Answer (score 1):

let $w = z-2\\z = w+2$

$\frac {w+3}{w^2+4w + 4 +w + 2 + 1}\\
\frac {w+3}{w^2+5w + 7}$

Now we have a to find the radius of convergence of series centered at 0.

$\frac {w+3}{(w + \frac {5 + i\sqrt 3}{2})(w + \frac {5 - i\sqrt 3}{2})}\\
\frac {A}{(w + \frac {5 + i\sqrt 3}{2})} + \frac {B}{(w + \frac {5 - i\sqrt 3}{2})}\\
\frac {A}{\frac {5+i\sqrt 3}{2}}\sum \frac {w^n}{(\frac {-5 + i\sqrt 3}{2})^n} + \frac {B}{\frac {-5 - i\sqrt 3}{2}}\sum \frac {w^n}{(\frac {-5 - i\sqrt 3}{2})^n} $

And what is the radius of convergence of those series?

I have done a little bit more work than is absolutely necessary, to show the motivation....

As soon as you had factored the denominator, you could have said.

$|\frac {5 + i\sqrt 3}{2}| = \sqrt 7$

Comment: Is it 2*sqrt(7) because its the distance between the two singularities? So if I divide by 2 thats the distance from 2 to one singularity?

Comment: It is the distance of the singularity from the center of the power series.

Comment: @JohnDoran It is $2\sqrt{7}$ in his answer because he didn't compute the absolute value properly. $\left|\frac{5+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\right|=\sqrt{7}$.

Comment: @totoro thanks..

Comment: @DougM i'm confused how you got from the partial fractions to the sums. Where is the w^n  and n exponents coming from? Are you using 1/1-z = sum z^n identity?

Comment: You are right, I am moving a little bit too quickly and getting sloppy.  I am using the  $\frac {1}{1-z} = \sum z^n$ identity.

Comment: @DougM how are you able to use this identity? Wouldn't A and w have to be equal in order to use it?

Comment: $\frac {a}{z+b} = \frac {a}{b} \frac {1}{1+\frac {z}{b}} = \frac ab \sum \frac {(-z)^n}{b^n}$

Comment: @DougM Thank you I get it now, greatly appreciated